# What are the powers of referee in a football match?

Tags: rules, football, officiating

What are the powers and duties of a referee in a football match(defined in the football laws)?

Comment: Suggest you read the FIFA Laws of the Game. The 2015/2016 version is located at the link below and the Powers and Duties of the referee are on pages 25-26 with duties of the assistant referees on page 29: http://www.fifa.com/mm/Document/FootballDevelopment/Refereeing/02/36/01/11/LawsofthegamewebEN_Neutral.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [2015/2016 FIFA Laws of the Game (PDF)](http://www.fifa.com/mm/Document/FootballDevelopment/Refereeing/02/36/01/11/LawsofthegamewebEN_Neutral.pdf), Law 5 (The Referee), Powers and Duties:

> The Referee:
>
> - enforces the Laws of the Game
> - controls the match in cooperation with the assistant referees and, where
>     applicable, with the fourth official
> - ensures that any ball used meets the requirements of Law 2
> - ensures that the players’ equipment meets the requirements of Law 4
> - acts as timekeeper and keeps a record of the match
> - stops, suspends or abandons the match, at his discretion, for any
>     infringements of the Laws
> - stops, suspends or abandons the match because of outside
>     interference of any kind
> - stops the match if, in his opinion, a player is seriously injured and ensures
>     that he is removed from the field of play. An injured player may only return
>     to the field of play after the match has restarted
> - allows play to continue until the ball is out of play if a player is, in his
>     opinion, only slightly injured
> - ensures that any player bleeding from a wound leaves the field of play. The
>     player may only return on receiving a signal from the referee, who must be
>     satisfied that the bleeding has stopped
> - allows play to continue when the team against which an offence has been
>     committed will benefit from such an advantage and penalises the original
>     offence if the anticipated advantage does not ensue at that time
> - punishes the more serious offence when a player commits more than one
>     offence at the same time
> - takes disciplinary action against players guilty of cautionable
>     and sending-off offences. He is not obliged to take this action immediately
>     but must do so when the ball next goes out of play
> - takes action against team officials who fail to conduct themselves in a
>     responsible manner and may, at his discretion, expel them from the field of
>     play and its immediate surrounds
> - acts on the advice of the assistant referees regarding incidents that he has
>     not seen
> - ensures that no unauthorised persons enter the field of play
> - indicates the restart of the match after it has been stopped
> - provides the appropriate authorities with a match report, which includes
>     information on any disciplinary action taken against players and/or team
>     officials and any other incidents that occurred before, during or after the
>     match

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia I got a page.

Almost same as **[Ben Miller](https://sports.stackexchange.com/users/1723/ben-miller)**'s answer. I'll add the contents and link below.

> The referee's powers and duties are described by Law 5 of the Laws of
>   the Game.   These include:
>
> **Powers**
>
> - stopping, suspending or terminating the match at his discretion, for any infringements of the Laws;
> - stopping, suspending or terminating the match because of outside interference of any kind;
> - stopping the match if, in his opinion, a player is seriously injured and ensuring that he is removed from the field of play. An
>     injured player may only return to the field of play after the match
>     has restarted;
> - allowing play to continue until the ball is out of play if a player is, in his opinion, only slightly injured;
> - allowing play to continue when the team against which an offence has been committed will benefit from such an advantage and penalizing
>     the original offence if the anticipated advantage does not ensue;
> - taking disciplinary action against players guilty of cautionable and sending-off offences. He is not obliged to take this action
>     immediately but must do so when the ball next goes out of play;
> - taking action against team officials who fail to conduct themselves in a responsible manner and may, at his discretion, expel them from
>     the field of play and its immediate surrounds.
>
> **Duties**
>
> - enforcing the Laws of the Game;
> - controlling the match in co-operation with the assistant referees and, where applicable, with the fourth official;
> - ensuring that any ball used meets the requirements of Law 2;
> - ensuring that the players' equipment meets the requirements of Law 4;
> - acting as timekeeper and keeping a record of the match;
> - ensuring that any player bleeding from a wound leaves the field of play. The player may only return on receiving a signal from the
>     referee, who must be satisfied that the bleeding has stopped;
> - punishing the more serious offence when a player commits more than one offence at the same time;
> - acting on the advice of the assistant referees regarding incidents that he has not seen;
> - ensuring that no unauthorised persons enter the field of play;
> - indicating the restart of the match after it has been stopped;
> - providing the appropriate authorities with a match report, which includes information on any disciplinary action taken against players
>     and/or team officials, substitutions and any other incidents that
>     occurred before, during or after the match.
>
> **Link : [Powers and duties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referee_(association_football)#Powers_and_duties)**